# The Issue is the click is working for the first time but not after that

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/base_data",
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(response) {
    $(response).each(function(index, value) {
      popup = L.marker([value.latitude, value.longitude]).addTo(map);
      popup.on("click", function() {
        var con = getMembers(value.id);
        // alert("CLicked"+value.id);
        // console.log(con);
        this.bindPopup(con).openPopup();
      });
    });
  },
  error: function() {

  }
});
```

Comment: add all relevant code to OP

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: [check this i think this is helpfull ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715274/jquery-click-function-doesnt-work-after-ajax-call)

Comment: Please add your question

Comment: If the popup is deleted when you close it, the event has no element to handle. If it is the case, you have to use event delegation... Or just hide the popup.

Comment: By the way, OP means _"Original Post"_ 